# form JSON date to JS date

Tags: javascript, json

My JSON date data is like below. how to convert to JS date?

```
"date":{"sec":1320919381,"usec":507000}}
```

is it ok?

```
new Date(obj["date"])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new Date(obj.date.sec * 1000); // pass milliseconds
```